# Model a One To Many Relationship With Existing Records In Spring Data JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, entity-relationship

I have 2 tables, TableA and TableB.
A One-Many should relationship exists between both tables.
Entering records into TableA is not a problem because it's the parent table.
My problem is with TableB, when a record is being inserted, it is not related to any record in TableA.
An action from the user needs to be performed to link records in TableB to a record in TableA.

My approach will be to create a nullable foreign key column on TableB, then update the column when the user performs the action.

OR Do I need to create a join table for this type of relationship?

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can find great examples of how to implement this with JPA/Hibernate and discussions about the pros/cons of each approach here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany